# weird behaviour of If statement in (t)csh

Tags: if-statement, csh

I have an if loop that's not quite doing what it's supposed to. 
I want the if loop to look for a particular file "if (-f JUN*[0-9].acc$RUN.nc)" and if it finds it, continue doing the indented things. 
If not, it should jump down past the endif and keep reading through the script.

At the moment, it's looking for the file ok (it has been able to go through the first "if" statement and do the right things when it finds the first file), but as soon as it doesn't find what it's looking for, it stops the whole script and returns the error:

DEC*[0-9].accE01Ccek0kA.nc: No match.

I've tried various combinations of if: ... else: pass and if ... then ... endif with colons and such in different places, but I still can't get it working.

Thanks for any help!

```
  setenv RUN $1                                 # Run number
  setenv BDIR /discover/nobackup/cekrause
  setenv MONDATA $BDIR/$RUN/data_files # Target directory
  setenv DATADIR $BDIR/$RUN                  # Run directory
  setenv EXECDIR /discover/nobackup/projects/giss/exec

  cd $DATADIR

  #### pdE JUN and DEC files ####
  if (-f JUN*[0-9].acc$RUN.nc) then
       mkdir tempplot
       cp JUN*[0-9].acc$RUN.nc tempplot
       cd tempplot
       pdE JUN*[0-9].acc$RUN.nc
  endif

  cd $DATADIR

  if (-f DEC*[0-9].acc$RUN.nc) then
       mkdir tempplot
       cp DEC*[0-9].acc$RUN.nc tempplot
       cd tempplot
       pdE DEC*[0-9].acc$RUN.nc
  endif

  (do some other things)
  exit
```

Comment: Alternatively, type `info bash` in your terminal.

Comment: BTW: there is no such thing as an "if loop". An `if` statement doesn't loop. If you want a loop, use `while`.

Comment: @Mat It's obvious that Claire uses csh instead of bash to execute the script (bash would already fail when it encounters the `setenv` line). The "bash" tag is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use csh or tcsh instead of bash, and the somewhat irrational behaviour that you just discovered is one of the reasons not to use csh for programming. And there are more of them. [**Much more.**](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) So, please: When you write a shell script, don't ever use (t)csh. Use bash, ksh, dash, zsh, or plain old sh; they are all much better suited for this task. Yes, the syntax is noticably different from csh, so you will have to rewrite parts of your script, but it pays off. Your script should look as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

export RUN=$1                                 # Run number
export BDIR=/discover/nobackup/cekrause
export MONDATA=$BDIR/$RUN/data_files          # Target directory
export DATADIR=$BDIR/$RUN                     # Run directory
export EXECDIR=/discover/nobackup/projects/giss/exec

cd "$DATADIR"

#### pdE JUN and DEC files ####
if [ -f JUN*[0-9].acc"$RUN".nc ] ; then   # note spaces around [, ], and semicolon before "then"
     mkdir tempplot
     cp JUN*[0-9].acc"$RUN".nc tempplot
     cd tempplot
     pdE JUN*[0-9].acc"$RUN".nc
fi                                        # bash uses "fi" instead of "endif"  

cd "$DATADIR"

if [ -f DEC*[0-9].acc"$RUN".nc ] ; then
     mkdir tempplot
     cp DEC*[0-9].acc"$RUN".nc tempplot
     cd tempplot
     pdE DEC*[0-9].acc"$RUN".nc
fi

(do some other things)
exit
```

Comment: Thanks so much! No wonder I was having so many problems - I didn't even know what language I was trying to code in (I was starting from a script I have that works and trying to modify it). I'll move to BASH from now on, it seems to make much more sense. Thanks for all your help!!

Answer (score 1):

If is not written like that in bash. it should be something like:

```
 if [ -f JUN*[0-9].acc$RUN.nc ] ; then
```

And yeah, please consult already available online resources on questions like these. It's not like there is no a single website with this stuff.

Comment: And keep in mind that this code will only work if there is _at most one_ file that matches the pattern. If there are two or more files, you'll get a syntax error. You need something more complicated in this case, e.g., an array assignment `FILES=(JUN*[0-9].acc$RUN.nc) ;` followed by a test `if [ -f "${FILES[0]}" ] ; then`.

Comment: The entire script isn't bash. If you use bash to run this script, you get `bash: setenv: command not found`.

Answer (score 0):

In `csh` if a glob such as `DEC*[0-9].accE01Ccek0kA.nc` fails to match a file then you get a `No match` error.  This means you pretty much cannot use `-f` with a glob.

You are ***much*** better off using `bash` for scripting because of numerous problems like this.   However, if you must use `csh` you can get past this particular quirk by including:

```
set nonomatch
```

before you use any globs.